# How to get the values from outside the class ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to solve the exercise 1 from the http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/ but I have no idea how to get "a" variable from the A class and its instance.

Here's the code:

```
class A
  def initialize
    @a = 11
    @@a = 22
    a = 33
  end
  @a = 1
  @@a = 2
  a = 3
end
```

Comment: You can't access `a` from outside its scope. it's called "local variable" for a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define this class, the output will be the local scoped variable `3`

```
class A
  def initialize
    @a = 11
    @@a = 22
    a = 33
  end
  @a = 1
  @@a = 2
  a = 3
end        #=> 3
```

You can access the instance and class variables as follows;

```
A.instance_variable_get(:@a) #=> 1
A.class_variable_get(:@@a)   #=> 2

A.new.instance_variable_get(:@a) #=> 11
A.class_variable_get(:@@a) #=> 22
```

For the other value, if you call `initialize` on this class and create a new object, this will return the last expression evaluated, which will be the local variable `a`

```
if A.respond_to?(:initialize, true)
  A.new.method(:initialize).call} #=> 33
end
```

Comment: No need for that `method(:initialize)` business. Just `send` it.

Comment: Also, your `respond_to` check is flawed (you check the wrong object) and unneeded (`initialize` _will_ be there)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are talking about [this exercise](http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/html/Exercise_1.html).

I am not sure how you could access a local scoped variable from outside. It's called local scoped for a reason. For others:

After the class is defined, try:

```
A.instance_variable_get(:@a) # => 1
A.class_variable_get(:@@a) # => 2
A.new.instance_variable_get(:@a) # => 11
A.class_variable_get(:@@a) # => 22
```

Edit: I played around a bit with this code, I guess I figured it:

```
a = class A
  def initialize
    @a = 11
    @@a = 22
    a = 33
  end
  @a = 1
  @@a = 2
  a = 3
end

A.instance_variable_get(:@a) # => 1
A.class_variable_get(:@@a) # => 2
a # => 3
A.new.instance_variable_get(:@a) # => 11
A.class_variable_get(:@@a) # => 22
A.new.method(:initialize).call # => 33 , basically we tricked Ruby into calling initialize method again, slick huh!
```

Edit: @RossMc beat me at last line

Comment: No need for that `method(:initialize)` business. Just `send` it.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped!